# Timeout error when importing private key to bitcoinABC

Tags: bitcoin-cash, ecash

When importing private key to bitcoinABC, error occurs!

error: couldn't connect to server: timeout reached (code 0)
(make sure server is running and you are connecting to the correct RPC port)

How can I solve the problem?